# CXF-RS Fuse Integration, No message body writer has been found for class org.apache.cxf.message.MessageContentsList, ContentType: text/html

Tags: spring-boot, jbossfuse, cxfrs

**Below is the routes configuration**

```java
@Component
public class CamelRoutes extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

           from("cxfrs://bean://rsServer").log("hello camel");
         
    }
}
```

**Below is the CXF configuration**

```java
@Configuration
public class CxfConfig {

        @Bean
        public SpringJAXRSServerFactoryBean rsServer() {
            SpringJAXRSServerFactoryBean factory = new SpringJAXRSServerFactoryBean();
            factory.setResourceClasses(CamelResource.class);
            factory.setAddress("/rest");
            return factory;
        }
    
    
}
```

**Below is the resource class**

```java
@Path("/camelresource")
public class CamelResource {

    @GET
    @Path("/hellocamel")    
    public String helloCamel() {
        System.out.println("hello how are you.");
        return "helloCamel()";
    }
}
```

server started.

http://localhost:8080/cxf

[CXF Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Egw2O.png)

on calling rest api "http://localhost:8080/cxf/rest/camelresource/hellocamel"
I am getting below error

**No message body writer has been found for class org.apache.cxf.message.MessageContentsList, ContentType: text/html**

Please suggest what is an issue. furthermore I want to return response from hellocamel endpoint.
early response will be highly appreciated.

Need solution, with example